# Ontology annotation type is missing in saved ontology file

Tags: annotations, owl, owl-api

I'm using OWL API 4.1. I add annotation with type XSD:string like that:

```
OWLAnnotationProperty annotationProperty = this.getDf().getOWLAnnotationProperty(annotationPropertyIri);
OWLLiteral lit = this.df.getOWLLiteral(annotationValue, range);
OWLAnnotation annotation = df.getOWLAnnotation(annotationProperty, lit);
this.getMng().applyChange(new AddOntologyAnnotation(this.getOnt(), annotation));
```

... I checked that here lit="test"^^xsd:string. But after I saved ontology (in ttl format) - there in no type ending - ^^xsd:string:

```
...
<http://semanticweb.rocks/whole-dataset-name/wheat-02> a owl:Ontology ;
    dc:description """test""" ;
    dc:source """http://mail.ru"""^^xsd:anyURI .
...
```

If I use other type (e.g. xsd:anyURI ) instead of ^^xsd:string the ending ^^xsd:anyURI is presented.

What is matter with ^^xsd:string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `xsd:string` type can be skipped for string literals, when there is no language tag. A literal typed with `xsd:string` is identical to a plain literal with no language tag.

If you load the ontology back into an `OWLOntology`, I expect you to see a `test^^xsd:string` literal attached to the ontology.

Comment: I have tried to create value - string + lang tag by this method: OWLLiteral lit = this.df.getOWLLiteral(literal, lang), result is the same. When I open saved ontology in Protege (it uses OWLAPI, isn't it?) - there is not type ending. But thank you for clarification - I hope that absence of string type is not such a big deal.